# I can not upload image on android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload a picture to my database and order them. My upload code looks like this-

```
package com.example.cagri.cafeorderapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.IOException; 

public class AddFood extends AppCompatActivity {

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
private ImageButton foodImage;
private static final int GELLERQ=1;
private EditText name, desc, price;
private Uri uri=null;
private StorageReference storageReference = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_food);

    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    desc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemDesc);
    price=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
    storageReference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Item");
}

public void imageButtonClicked(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
// Show only images, no videos or anything else
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
     startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 
  PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foodImageButton);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void addItemButtonClicked(View view)
{
    String name_text=name.getText().toString().trim();
    String desc_text=desc.getText().toString().trim();
    String price_text=price.getText().toString().trim();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name_text) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_text) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(price_text))
    {
        StorageReference filepath=storageReference.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                final Uri downloadurl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Toast.makeText(AddFood.this,"Image uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

But the error I'm getting is

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference

Everything is okey and I can place the item image in `imagebutton` but when I click add item the process stops.

Comment: `uri` is null.  You will have to check for that and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

(And other stuff) Is not a good way for pick image unfortunately

You need to use a cursor with file selection "on traditional way" **for getting real path**

See my example of it

*This file contains an example of calling of cursorloader*

[ActivityMainPopups.java](https://github.com/androidovshchik/VKAdvancedPosting/blob/master/android/src/rf/androidovshchik/vkadvancedposting/ActivityMainPopups.java)

*This file contains needed util methods*

[CursorPicker.java](https://github.com/androidovshchik/VKAdvancedPosting/blob/master/android/src/rf/androidovshchik/vkadvancedposting/components/CursorPicker.java)

**OR**

If you are deal with rxjava i will suggest this library for use https://github.com/MLSDev/RxImagePicker

It will give you a correct uri

Comment: I don't now how to use rxjava but i wil try another things.